# Listing printers on remote machines. Not seeing the same results as I would if I were logged on locally as the user

Tags: vbscript

My script is supposed to list all the printers installed on a remote machine and write that data to a text file while designating if the printer is `Local` or `Network`. When I run the script against my local machine with my profile logged on I get the following results:

```
Local
Microsoft XPS Document Writer

Network
\\PrintServer\PT-NJ-CPR-B-CORPIT-1

Network
\\PrintServer\PT-NJ-CPR-B-ITTEMP-1

Network
\\PrintServer\CPR5A26D1A
```

These results are exactly what I want however when I run the same script against a remote machine I still get results but they seem to be for a more generic user

```
Local
Send To OneNote 2010

Local
Microsoft XPS Document Writer

Local
Fax
```

My question is how do I customize my script to truly impersonate the logged on user thus returning me the full results even from a remote machine?

```
Const ForAppending = 8
Const ForReading = 1

Dim WshNetwork, objPrinter, intDrive, intNetLetter, fso

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set InputFile = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\xVBS Scripts\Printer Scripts\Computers.txt", 1)

Do Until InputFile.AtEndOfStream
  strComputer = InputFile.ReadLine

Set WshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colInstalledPrinters = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Printer")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem",,48)
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each objItem in colItems
    UserName = objItem.UserName
    arrUserName = Split(UserName, "\", -1, 1)
    varUserName = arrUserName(1)
Next

filOutput = varUserName & ".txt"

If objFSO.FileExists(filOutput) Then
    objFSO.DeleteFile(filOutput)
End If

Set objOutputFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile (filOutput, ForAppending, True)

For Each objPrinter in colInstalledPrinters
    If objPrinter.Attributes And 64 Then
        strPrinterType = "Local"
        strTest = Left(objPrinter.Name, 2)
        objOutputFile.WriteLine(strPrinterType)
        objOutputFile.WriteLine(objPrinter.Name)
        objOutputFile.WriteLine(vbNewLine)
    Else
        strPrinterType = "Network"
        strTest = Left(objPrinter.Name, 2)
        objOutputFile.WriteLine(strPrinterType)
        objOutputFile.WriteLine(objPrinter.Name)
        objOutputFile.WriteLine(vbNewLine)
    End If
Next

Wscript.Sleep 1500 

MsgBox "Printer mapping report is located" & vbNewLine & "in the following directory: " &  filOutput , vbInformation, "Report Located At"
WshShell.Run "Notepad " & filOutput,1,False
Loop
InputFile.Close
Wscript.Quit
```

Comment: I dont think there is an actual answer to this. The more I learn about VB Script and Powershell it appears as if WMI is most useful when run interactively. It doesn't know how to process users who are not currently logged in. I bypass this problem by running the script as a GPO Link/Enforced that calls the script as a log on script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think there is an actual answer to this. The more I learn about VB Script and Powershell it appears as if WMI is most useful when run interactively. It doesn't know how to process users who are not currently logged in. I bypass this problem by running the script as a GPO Link/Enforced that calls the script as a log on script. – JRN just now   edit